# AppSync 4XX Errors

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-appsync, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

How to capture AppSync 4XX errors & 5XX errors in CloudWatch log insights.

I've setup an alert for both these metrics and getting frequent alarms but couldn't get the pattern to query the logs in log insights.

Tried checking for Status code in the Log Type: RequestSummary , but the count of 4XX isn't matching with the count from alert.